# Im having problems in WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-shortcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xouXW.jpg**)

[strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X80C7.jpg)**

Hello, I'm having a problem with my WooCommerce project. When I show a product on my page I have this error

```
"Warning: Undefined array key "before_widget" 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\thoitrang\wp-content\plugins\elementor-addon-widgets\vendor\codeinwp\elementor-extra-widgets\widgets\woo\recent-products.php on line 76"
```

The code:

```
        if ( '' == $title ) {
            $title = __( 'New In', 'elementor-addon-widgets' );
        }

        $limit = ( ! empty( $instance['limit'] ) ) ? absint( $instance['limit'] ) : 4;
        if ( '' == $limit ) {
            $limit = 4;
        }
        $columns = ( ! empty( $instance['columns'] ) ) ? absint( $instance['columns'] ) : 4;

        if ( '' == $columns ) {
            $columns = 4;
        }

        $args = apply_filters(
            'elementor-addon-widgets_product_categories_args', array(
                'limit'   => $limit,
                'columns' => $columns,
                'title'   => $title,
            )
        );

        echo $args['before_widget']; // line 76
```

Comment: What is unclear? The array does not contain any element under that key.

Comment: echo $args['before_widget']??""; // solved

Comment: thanks you but not working.  
Echo $args['before_widget']??"";

Comment: CBroe : so how can it fix it? . im not a programmer.